# assigning mysql array result to php variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I've assigned mysql array results to variables hundreds of times but for some reason the variable assignment is not working for me in this particular script and I have no idea why.

The query works on the database and also produces results from the looping code. But when I then go to do my usual variable assignment no value is transferred.

```
$pcode = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE suburb like('%$suburb%') && state like('%$state%') && category like('%delivery area%')");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($pcode);
($rows = mysql_num_rows($pcode));
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    echo "".mysql_result($pcode,$j, 'suburb').", ".mysql_result($pcode,$j, 'pcode')."";

$pcode1 = "".mysql_result($pcode,$j, 'pcode')."";

echo "$pcode1";
```

I can't figure out why it is not working this time round. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, 
Rosie

Comment: Your `$pcode1` assignment is not in the `for` loop.

Comment: Why do you concatenate empty strings to everything?

Comment: What array result are you talking about? `mysql_result` returns a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Barmar, this seems to have done the trick:

```
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    echo $pcode1 = " ".mysql_result($pcode,$j, 'pcode')."<br>";
    $pcode2 = ($pcode1+10);
    echo " result1: $pcode1<br>
        result2: $pcode2<br>";


}
```